# sperical law of cosines formula

Tags: formula, equation, geo

I'm tring to calculate a point's longitude from the other point's longitude. They have the same latitude and the distance between them is known. I try to use the **sperical law of cosines** formula.

```
# 'lat' short for 'latitude', 'lng' short for 'longitude'.
# EARTH_RADIUS = 6371000.0, unit is meter.
#
distance = Math.acos( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) + 
           Math.cos(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2) * 
           Math.cos(lng2-lng1)) * EARTH_RADIUS
```

If the two point's latitude are equal(lat1 == lat2), i can calculate lng2 from lng1 with distance. So i reason the formula from **sperical law of cosines** formula

```
# lat1 == lat2 == lat
# 'distance' and 'lng' are known 
lng2 = Math.acos((Math.cos(distance/EARTH_RADIUS) - Math.sin(lat)*Math.sin(lat))/(Math.cos(lat)*Math.cos(lat))) + lng
```

This formula works very well,  except some situations.

Like

```
lat_degrees =  -89.8345981836319  
lng_degrees = 96.42309331893921
lat = lat1 = lat2 = (lat_degrees * Math::PI)/180 # -1.567909520510494
lng = (lng_degrees * Math::PI)/180  # 1.682900453373236 
distance = 67544.06725769254
```

This will apper the error

```
Math::DomainError: Numerical argument is out of domain - "acos"
```

Because the value in Math.acos(value) equal to -2.5100189069914602, which smaller than -1. I have no idea about that. Is the derived formual wrong?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: If you can read a little javascript, check out https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/PMxcDEnwNak

Comment: @WTP The programming language is ruby.

Comment: @anirudh444 Thanks for your advise, but it does not answer my question. It is another formual _'haversine'_ for calculate distance between two points.

Comment: Howard is probably right.  Start with the original formula, fix lat1, lat2, and lng, and plug in lng2 = lng + 180 degrees to see if two points at that latitude could ever be 67544 apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your formula. I didn't do the calculations but I suppose the point is that you are (very!!) near to the south pole and there basically are no two points which lie apart such large distance.

Answer (score 0):

just add a compare before it:

```
if lat1 == lat2 and lng1 == lng2
  return 0
end
```